# Nowhere had she less expected to see them than on this boat

Tags: sentence-meaning

I found this sentence -

> Nowhere had she less expected to see them than on this boat

Does it mean "she least expected to see them on the boat"?

Answer (score 2):

I think it means that of all places she didn't expect them to see, she least expected to see them on this boat.